# CakePHP, GET Parameters and routing

Tags: cakephp, url-routing

I am fairly new to cakephp but I have a question relating to urls and parameters. I would like to be able to have a url that looks like a standard url e.g:

```
http://www.mysite.com/controller/myaction?arg=value&arg2=val
```

I would like that url to map to an action in my controller as follows:

```
function myaction($arg = null, $arg2 = null)
{
   // do work
}
```

I realize that cakephp has routing as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration), however, honestly this seems over engineered and results in a url string that is nonstandard.

In my current situation the url is being generated and invoked by an external (billing) system that knows nothing about cake and doesn't support the cake url format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have your URL in any form. It's just CakePHP allows you to retrieve the variable passed through GET from the variable `$this->params['url']`

```
function myaction()
{
  if(isset($this->params['url']['arg'])) 
    $arg = $this->params['url']['arg'];
  if(isset($this->params['url']['arg2']))
    $arg2 = $this->params['url']['arg2'];
}
```

Comment: You meant to say 'isset', right? is_set is not a php function.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in AppController for CakePHP 2.x

```
class AppController extends Controller {

....

/***
     * Recupera los Named envias por URL
     * si es null $key emtraga el array completo de named
     *
     * @param String $key
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getNamed($key=null){
        // Is null..?
        if(is_string($key)==true){
            // get key in array
            return Hash::get($this->request->param('named'), $key);
        }else{
            // all key in array
            return $this->request->param('named');
        }
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Not because I have an external system, but because I don't like to put all parameters into the URL-path. In my example, I have some search queries that are assembled and passed to the controller. IMHO, these queries should be GET parameters and not part of the URL-path.

One advantage of using GET parameters is that the order of the given parameters is not important, in contrast to passing params via the URL path.

To solve this problem in a generic way, I'm replacing all method arguments with the value of the GET-param, if one with the same name is given:

```
class MyController extends AppController 
{
    function test($var1 = null, $var2 = "content2")
    {
        foreach (get_defined_vars() as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($this->params['url'][$key])) {
                $getvalue = $this->params['url'][$key];
                $$key = $getvalue;
                CakeLog::write("debug", "Setting:$key to $getvalue");
            }
        }
        CakeLog::write("debug", print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
    }
}
```

Now I can access this controller method and pass parameters via GET like this:

```
http://myapp/mycontroller/test?var1=foo&var2=bar
```